# Override method in PyCharm

Tags: python, methods, overriding, pycharm

Why to override a method in PyCharm not get how to access them? For example :

```
class A ( object):
    def __init__ (self, i = 1):
        self.i = i

    def __f1_a (self):
        return ( self.i )


class B (A) :
    def __init__ (self, j = 2):
        super () . __init__ ()
        self.j = 0

    def __f1_a (self):
        return ( self.j )


class C ( B):
    def __init__ (self, c = 100):
        self.c = c
```

Why in the `B` class PyCharm does not tell us how to access the two methods  `__f1_a(self)` ? They do not appear when trying to access the methods of an object of class `B` , but we can in the following ways (imagine that `b` is an instance of class `B`):

```
b._A__f1_a( )

b._B__f1_a( )
```

Both expressions are correct. Why not tell us PyCharm  about it? Should we know it? In my opinion it would be much more clear they appeared within each class of methods that can be accessed in the way we must write it. Why not do that PyCharm? Instead in class `B` appears only a private method in a way not accessible to the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

Using two leading underscores in an attribute name implements "name mangling" (except the special case of leading and trailing double underscores for built-in "magic methods"), which as you have found means that the attribute can only be accessed externally as `_classname__attrname`.

This name mangling is used *specifically* to prevent access to the attribute. A single underscore does not implement name mangling, and indicates "private by convention" (i.e. it is accessible, but it's polite not to use it!)

A better question might be:

1. why are you trying to access double-underscore methods; or
2. why are you naming them like that if you want to be able to access them?

Comment: Totally agree, the question is really a curiosity about how PyCharm displays the override methods. Other IDE's like PyScripter or Visual Studio (with PTVS) represent this form of access to methods. But, of course, the programmer should know it. Thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: Although I still think it would be better to represent him in the way we can access it, although that would be illogical to try to access the method. PyScripter do that, for example.